# how to install Tensorflow for deeplearnig on Mac 2020 M1 (silicon)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

first I downloaded anaconda then I have made virtual env, and over there I tried to install Tensorflow typing " conda install tensorflow " but it didn't worked. can anyone guide me up to properly setup tensorflow on Mac m1, and my python version is 3.8

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow) says, try using:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

If you want to install a specific version, use:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=2.3
# 2.3 is an example
```

Answer (score 0):

I've installed it in my MAC using Homebrew.
First of all install the Homebrew. It find the missing packages for mac. read it out at https://brew.sh

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

After the installation complete just, type the given below command in the terminal

```
brew install tensorflow
```

[image]

Comment: @ Salman Khan do we need to install the brew in the conda virtual env and then use brew install tensorflow?

Comment: Brew can only download the missing packages and install them. It will not install it in the V env conda, but in the MAC directly.

Comment: thanks for it, can we connect somewhere els like on link dine so incase I get any trouble, you can help me out, thanks in advance, then you can share me you're linkdine id.